# Extracting fitted values of a variogram model

Tags: r, gstat

How can I extract the fitted values (not parameters!) of a variogram model? I intend to draw the theoretical variogram in the Excel software.

I used the fit.variogram in gstat package as follows:

```
library(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
vgm1 <- variogram(log(zinc)~1, meuse)
fit.variogram(vgm1, vgm(1, "Sph", 300, 1))
fit.variogram(vgm1, vgm("Sph"))
```

I need the set of data used in plot function in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are functions variogramLine (spatial vgm)  and variogramSurface (spatio-temporal vgm) in gstat that will evaluate the vgm model for a provided set of distances.